# How to read and filter a raw audio file with python?

Tags: java, python, audio

I got a `.raw` file from recording, it was written by the write method from the Java class `AudioOutputStream` (I wrote bytes).

I want to filter this audio file with a Python filter. [Here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/ButterworthBandpass) it is the guide I'm using, it filters a list of float numbers (the variable x in the guide).

My problem is the different types, bytes and floats. Is there a way to make this filter work with that `.raw` audio?

I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found two useful java classes: `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` to write floats for my Python script to use.

First I read float values from the `.raw` file with the `readFloat` method which reads 4 bytes as a float.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputName);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

ArrayList<Float> fbuffer = new ArrayList<Float>();

try {
    while(dis.available()>0){
       float f = dis.readFloat(); //read 4 bytes as float 
       // this fails if it is not 4x
       fbuffer.add(f);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //nothing happens, there are 1,2 or 3 bytes at the end we are going to ignore
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
dis.close();
is.close();
```

This way I create a file with the float values. This file is read by the python script. Here I use

```
fin = open('fileWithFloatsName')
floatList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fin]
floatList = destringifyList(floatList)
fin.close()
```

I get the list of floats, perform the filter as in [here](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/ButterworthBandpass) and get a new list of floats. I write this result in a new file that java is going to read with a `Scanner` object.

Finally we create a new `.raw` file and write the floats as bytes with the `writeFloat` method.

That's all. If someone suggest something better (partially or not), I will appreciate it.